# Playframework 2.5 : unable to access SQLite db file in stage mode

Tags: java, sqlite, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have an application.conf file with my database configuration : `db.default.url = "jdbc:sqlite:public/db/mydatabase.db"`. This works fine in development mode.
When I try to deploy in production, after done `./activator clean compile stage` and `./activator start` the application try to connect to the database during 30 seconds and finally exits with an exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'public/db/mydatabase.db': '/path/to/app/target/universal/stage/public' does not exist
```

I tried to specify absolute path with a specific prod.conf including application.conf and overriding `db.default.url`. I tried also to start with an argument to the command line (`-Ddb.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:public/db/mydatabase.db"`) the output is always the same.
How can I solve this problem ?

EDIT : the prod.conf configuration doesn't seem to override the application.conf statements... When I change directly the application.conf file with production specific properties, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play does not package the assets in the `stage`/`dist` tasks. In production, the assets are in a jar that is loaded when you start the app  and not in the filesystem (ie a "public" folder). so you can't load it that way.

Move your SQLite file to the `conf` directory and change the `db.default.url` line to match the new path.

Comment: someone from play should fix this then - this is really annoying!